# what is syntactically wrong with this query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{a: {b: 1, c: 2}}
```

```
db.getCollection("col").aggregate([
  { $match: { "a.b": { $or: [2, 3] } }  },
])
```

It is complaining that it doesn't recognize the `$or` operator.

Comment: the second answer explains that `$in` is recommended, but never said that `$or` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage states that:

> The query syntax is identical to the [read operation query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#std-label-read-operations-query-argument) syntax

If we inspect the documentation for the [`$or`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator, you need to pass it [expressions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions), or more specifically,  [expression objects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expression-objects). Expression objects have the form `{ <field1>: <expression1>, ... }`.

So the correct way to perform this query using `$or` would be to do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "a.b": 2
        },
        {
          "a.b": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Or as the other answer suggested, if both expressions are inspecting the same field, you can use [`$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#mongodb-query-op.-in). The syntax you would use for `$in` is more like what you tried initially: `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }`. Put together it might look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "a.b": {
        $in: [
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```